# How to Convert a TextField.text to int without crashing your app? in Swift2

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to programming and i am working on an app which has two `textfield`'s and want to calculate the sum of those two `textfield`'s without letting my app crash.I know i have to do something like var `a = Int(textFieldOne.text!)!` but my app crashes when one of them or both of them are empty.can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Don't make force unwrap, use if let or guard

```
 if let a = textFieldOne.text, b = Int(a) {
    //... success...
 }
 else{
    //.... handle nil  ....
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may check the value is Empty or not by following code so your app wont be crashed:

```
if let text = textFieldOne.text{
   print("not nill \(text)")
}
```